# How to get function parameter values from an HTML Page using bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bookmarklet

The code below saves data entered in textarea using `saveFieldData()`.I want to use a Delete Button as a bookmarklet which will make this field blank and save the same in the server.

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="49" name="Synonym" id="Synonym" onchange="saveFieldData(85261, this, 'docProductInfo', 'Synonym', 84796);"></textarea>
```

So here is my bookmarklet

```
javascript:(function(){var sy=document.getElementById("Synonym");sy.value="";saveFieldData(85261,sy, 'docProductInfo', 'Synonym', 84796);})();
```

It deletes the data perfectly  but the problem is whenever the page reloads   it assigns some new values as function parameters as a result my code fails to work.For example after page reloads the function parameter changes like this

```
saveFieldData(85261, this, 'docProductInfo', 'Synonym', 84789);
```

basically the last parameter changes.So,Is there any way so that my bookmarklet will detect that parameter automatically and delete that field successfully?

Comment: Do you need a function that calculates the value of a url parameter?

Comment: No I just need to get that parameter value automatically so that even if page reloading changes that value my bookmarklet will get it automatically from that html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to invoke the `onchange` handler you don't need to know it's parameters:

```
var sy=document.getElementById("Synonym");
var fn=sy.onchange;
sy.value="";
fn.call(sy);
```

Or more simply, since the onchange handler doesn't use any `this` within it:

```
fn();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot slebetman. it worked like a charm.Could you please suggest me something that can be referred  to get a good knowledge on javascripts?However, finally ,I will say StackOverflow is a superb forum.Really appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no single resource for good knowledge of modern javascript programming. The classic reference is the Rhino book (Javascript: The Definitive Guide) but I've never read that cover to cover. Also some of the code examples are now considered not quite good practice. My first introduction to how clean javascript code can be is Douglas Crockford's talks on youtube. I also strongly recommend Crockford's book: Javascript: The Good Parts

Comment: Also, make sure you'e familiar with all the reference sites: MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/, MSDN IE reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh828809, quirksmode for checking browser compatibility - http://www.quirksmode.org/, and caniuse for checking the state of html5 technologies - http://caniuse.com/

Comment: Thank you [slebetman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/167735/slebetman) for your reply.i will get through this.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your page, I can't give you an ideal answer. There could easily be a better way, but based only on what you have shown, the only answer I see is to use a regular expression something like this:

```
sy = document.getElementById("Synonym");
id = sy.onchange.toString().match(/saveFieldData\(.+?,.+?,.+?,.+?,\s*(\d+)\)/)[1];
```

Comment: @DGThanks a lot for the code.I tried this code but it did not work for me .Then I found that `sy.onchange` is actually a function ,not a string.So I used `String(sy.onchange)` and surprisingly it worked thanks again for the suggestion.So the modified code is 
`sy = document.getElementById("Synonym");
id = String(sy.onchange).match(/saveFieldData\(.+?,.+?,.+?,.+?,\s*(\d+)\)/)[1];`

Comment: Good catch. The more standard way would be `sy.onchange.toString().match(...)`. I've updated my answer to reflect that. But I see that slebetman gave you an answer that was a better way. I was too fixated on your "problem" and lost sight of your actual goal.